# Problem with simulating correctly my robot when using EffortJointInterface

Tags: ros, gazebo, control, simulation

Hello everyone i'm simulating a differential drive robot on **gazebo 11.0** (i'm using **ROS noetic**), and i'm trying to control each wheel separately using **velocity control** and using an **EffortJointInterface**, but my robot don't show up correctly whel i use the **effort interface**, **but if i use a velocity interface my robot is simulated correctly**.

My robot look like this when using velocity interface and work well:

[image]

But once i use an effort interface my robot is no longuer showed correctly and not moving:
[image]

Here are my codes:

-Transmissions:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot>

<!-- Transmission 1 -->
  <transmission name="tran1">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="wheel1_joint">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="motor1">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  
  <!-- Transmission 2 -->
  <transmission name="tran2">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="wheel2_joint">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="motor2">
      <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
  
  
  </robot>
```

-the Yaml control file:

```
carbot:
  joint_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 50  

  joint1_velocity_controller:
    type: effort_controllers/JointVelocityController
    joint: wheel1_joint
    pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
  joint2_velocity_controller:
    type: effort_controllers/JointVelocityController
    joint: wheel2_joint
    pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
```

- my control launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <rosparam file="$(find robot_control)/config/carbot_control.yaml" command="load"/>

  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
    output="screen" ns="/carbot" args="joint1_velocity_controller joint2_velocity_controller joint_state_controller"/>

  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"
    respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="/joint_states" to="/carbot/joint_states" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

thank you for your answers. (i'm new here)

Comment: Welcome at RSE. Please always add the versions of ROS, ros-control, and gazebo to your questions.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, with a similar wheeled configuration. Whenever I try to spin a wheel by feeding an effort to it through a transmission, I am unable to do so, unless the effort is above some value. For smaller efforts, the wheel remains static. In case of a velocity, everything works fine.
Check my question for some insight: [question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/110146/joint-does-not-move-after-applying-effort-to-it) EDIT 1:
I am trying to overcome this issue by coding a gazebo plugin which simulate the wheel dynamic plant, because I couldn't solve the aforemention